# I want to install composer using composersetup.exe and but it gave me this error through installation

Tags: laravel

The Composer installer script was not successful [exit code 1].  Your proxy settings may be causing this error.  Script Output: The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I want to use composer to create laravel project

Comment: What happens if you try to go to that URL in the web browser on the server?

Comment: [The Composer installer script was not successful exit code 1](https://github.com/composer/windows-setup/issues/91#issuecomment-485887391)